# Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Invalid column name 'VSERV'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I believe my syntax is correct.  Does anybody have any idea why I get the following exception?

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'VSERV'.
```

The following is my script:

```
SELECT * FROM VSERV.MRC.dbo.F_Stage F
LEFT OUTER JOIN VSERV.MRC.dbo.ACExtensionBase A
ON F.SNo = A.SN and F.Type = [VSERV].MRC.dbo.Lookup_Type_Name(A.A_Type)
```

The syntax looks fine to me and the the invalid column name is referring to my server....Any suggestions?

Comment: You dont need the server name.

Comment: @Mihai You do when you are using a linked server.

Comment: Im on a virtual server....does that make a diff?

Comment: Im calling the function from a diff DB on a diff server.

Comment: @JeffOrris What version of SQL Server are you using?, are you actually querying a linked server named `VSERV`?, what version of SQL Server does that server has?

Comment: Anyway, you can't directly use a function on a linked server. [this](http://danieladeniji.wordpress.com/2010/11/27/microsoft-sql-server-calling-user-defined-function-over-linked-server-the-wire/) is an example, and [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/485517/udf-calls-are-not-allowed-over-linked-servers) is another link that shows you that

Comment: Version 2012.  My query window is on a diff server named RSERV and Im querying from this server(that DB sits on) so I don't have to switch DB for efficiency.  That is way Im using the VSERV prefix.  I would like to know why this isnt working for future exception I might get

Comment: Well, as I said, this isn't working because SQL Server doesn't support the use of functions on linked servers directly. [Here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14063/how-can-i-call-a-remote-user-defined-function-with-parameters) is yet another link

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Could I do this using SSIS as a workaround in case needed?

Comment: Could you do a Cross Apply?

CROSS APPLY VERV.MRC.dbo.Lookup_Type_Name(A.A_Type) B

Comment: I will try.  I just checked and the servers are not linked

Comment: @HKImpact CROSS APPLY did not work....didn't understand "CROSS"

Answer (score 0):

try to remove `[]`. Using `[]`, Sql Server thinks you're referring to a column

EDIT: If you think it's not connected, look at this link, maybe should help: [sp_addlinkedserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx)

Comment: I did remove the [], still get the exception

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is that its not connecting to the server

Comment: The removal of [] has nothing to do with the reported error.